# How to create drawHitFunc for circle around the line that makes up it's perimeter?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am trying to add drawHitFunc for the circle around the line that makes up it's perimeter. Below is the code that I have tried.

```
  drawHitFunc: function (context) {        
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(0, 0, this.getRadius()+20, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStrokeShape(this);
 }
```

This code gives hit function outside and inside the cricle. But I want it to be only around the the perimeter and I didn't see any way to do that. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use strokeShape(this) rather then fillStrokeShape(this)

You can try out the following code

```
drawHitFunc: function (context) {        
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(0, 0, this.getRadius(), 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.closePath();
    context.strokeShape(this);
 }
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bijaybhandari1989/B34xz/

Answer (score 1):

I have got the better solution. We can simply do the following:

```
drawHitFunc: function (context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(0, 0, this.getRadius(), 0, (Math.PI * 2), false)
    context.closePath();
    context.setAttr('lineWidth', 20);
    context.setAttr('strokeStyle', this.colorKey);
    context.stroke();
}
```